# Correspondence between Riemannian metrics and Euclidean embeddings

Tags: riemannian-geometry, moduli-spaces, embeddings, metric-embeddings, isometry-groups

Given a sufficiently smooth manifold M,

- a Riemannian metric on M induces an isometric embedding into Euclidean space by Nash's theorem, (non-canonically, non-uniquely)
- an embedding of M into Euclidean space induces a Riemannian metric on M by pullback of the induced metric. (naturally)

So, there is a surjection from the set of Euclidean embeddings (say, for fixed target dimension) to the set of Riemannian metrics on M, in the appropriate smoothness categories.

Is there more structure to this correspondence? For instance, could it be continuous in some cases, perhaps with the appropriate topologies and after appropriate quotients on the space of metrics and the space of embeddings?

A previous question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362144/smooth-isometric-embeddings-of-riemannian-manifolds) notes, among other things, that the isometric embedding can be quite rigid in some cases (ex: positive curvature metrics on S2 embed uniquely in R3, presumably modulo Euclidean motions).

Originally asked in:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3851841/correspondence-between-riemannian-metrics-and-euclidean-embeddings